# Lost "edit item" form after exporting to excel

Tags: excel, export

When I export a list from a SharePoint site to Excel and then import this list to another site, the list content is untouched, but all columns change to "single line of text" only.

It is a problem because I need to have names "clickable" in fields like (created by, modified by etc..). The data is there, but there is no longer "person or Group" form but "single line of text".

How to keep the form the same without having all fields single line of text only. I cannot change this even in SharePoint Designer 2013 when I click change column type, there is no option to change it back to "person or group".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you exported the list to Excel and then created a list using the "Import Excel Spreadsheet" list template. SharePoint thinks that all data are plain text and creates Single line of text for all the columns, and i'm unsure if setting the columns in excel to number as an example would change anything.

Either you could recreate the list with the right set of columns and then use quick edit to paste the data from the Excel sheet (100 rows at the time), save the edit and then repeat.

Or what you could do is go to the list settings and find the option "Save list as template" and check "Include all content".

This will create a list template with the columns types and the data intact that you can find on the site collections List Template gallery. If the site that you would want to have to list in exists in the same site collection, you can create it from Site Content - Add an app.

Otherwise you would need to download a copy of the list template and add it to the List Template Gallery in the site collection were you wanna use it.

[Manage list templates](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Manage-list-templates-c3884ad1-bc49-44b8-b3d6-3bc6a01eb393)

Comment: There is another thing, I have full control and when I click save as template an error pops up saying: "Sorry, you don't have access to this page" please help

Comment: That is weird as Owner permissions should be enough. I think that you do not have access to the actual root site collection. Ask your administrator to help you/anyone that is site collection administrator for the site.